# C++ Undefined reference to MIDI function

Tags: c++, reference, undefined, midi

I simply want to print the amount of connected MIDI inputs. What in the world am I doing wrong?

Using Code::Blocks and GNU GCC Compiler.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d", midiInGetNumDevs());
    return 0;
}
```

I get *undefined reference to `midiInGetNumDevs@0'* upon compiling.

[midiInGetNumDevs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505706/using-mmsystem-h-in-visualstudio-2008

Answer (score 1):

You need to link with with `winmm.lib`.  In Visual Studio, you do this by adding it to the *Additional Dependencies* in your project properties.

Right-click on the project, select *Properties*, then *Linker*, then *Input*.  Add `winmm.lib` to the list of files in *Additional Dependencies*.

**Edit:** just noticed you are using GCC.  In this case, maybe the solution linked in the comments would be better.  Add `#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")` after your headers.

Answer (score 0):

If you do take a look at [midiInGetNumDevs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you will see that it requires `Winmm.lib`. You will need to add it to your projects so that the function can get linked to it.